# TypeError: null spread operator is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo

just can't seem to fix this null spread operator which is occurring when my charities (deconstructed from props) is empty. How do I best allow for this case? Any advice would be great. The error is occurring in the onCompleted function.

```
const Causes = ({ causes, charities }) => {

const [charitiesList, setCharitiesList] = useState(charities);
const causeIds = _.map(causes.edges, i => i.node.databaseId);
var causeYoutubeIds

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CHARITIES_BY_CAUSE, {
    variables: {
        "id": causeIds
    },
    onCompleted(dt) {
        const getCharitiesByCause = _.map(dt.charities.edges, i => ({ charity: i.node }));
        setCharitiesList([...charitiesList , ...getCharitiesByCause]);
    }
})

return (
    <div>
        <div className="columns is-multiline">
            <div className="column">
                <h2 className={styles.heading}>Charities Involved</h2>
                <div className={styles.causeContainer}>
                    {
                        charitiesList &&
                        charitiesList.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <div className={styles.charityCard}>
                                    <Img src={item.charity.Charity.logo.mediaItemUrl} />
                                    {item.charity.title}
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Null values usually get ignored in spread

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought. The error I get is "TypeError: charitiesList is not iterable"

Comment: Error basically says either of `charitiesList` or `getCharitiesByCause` is not iterable. Please console.log both and also log typeof to see if they are iterable type or not

Comment: You might not be passing an object or an array. Please follow what @AtinSingh wrote.\

Comment: Hmm so when I             console.log(charitiesList, getCharitiesByCause)
I get ->     null, [{...}, {...}]

Comment: Anyone know how to deal with this null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it seems like. `useState(charities);` This charities is coming null. If it should have a value then you need to fix it. Or you can just add a check. `useState(charities || []);`

Comment: Ahhh that fixed it! Didn't realise I could have a conditional in useState. Thanks a lot